# Angular 7 project upgrade http authorization error

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on upgrading an Angular project from 5.2 to version 7. With a few minor problems I have the code working. However I am now getting 401 Authorization errors accessing my .NET webapi REST service. I would normally assume it was a problem with the REST service, but the REST service has not changed and I can type in the REST URL in my browser and get results.

Has something changed with HttpClient that would cause an authorization error going across ports (from localhost:4200 to localhost:56263) between these Angular versions?

The code is simple, but here it is if that helps:

```
getUserInfo(runAsUser: boolean): Observable<UserInfo> {
  return this.http.get(`${environment.baseServer}/GetUserInfo/${runAsUser ? 1  : 0}`) as Observable<UserInfo>;
}
```

This translates into:

> http://localhost:56263/a360/GetUserInfo/0

The subscription is:

```
this.userInfoSubscription = this.dataService.getUserInfo(false)
  .subscribe(user => {
    // Removed
  }, error => {
    this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'An error was encountered while loading user info, refresh browser to try again: ' + this.userMessageService.getBadRequestMessage(error) });
  });
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: @AmitChigadani - I've added code, but it is pretty simple.

Comment: @MikeWitt have you switched from `HttpModule` and the `Http` service to `HttpClientModule` and the `HttpClient`?

Comment: In new `httpClient` we can set expected return type of `get()` as `this.http.get<UserInfo>(${environment.baseServer}/GetUserInfo/${runAsUser ? 1  : 0})`. Not sure, if that has something to do with this here.

Comment: @TalhaJunaid - Yes I've switched.

Comment: @AmitChigadani - I can see the request in my network tab. That would make me think it is a server side problem. Except that I haven't changed the server at all and that I can run the URL from the browser. It was accepting requests from localhost:4200 earlier, but maybe I should recheck that.

Comment: Does the request work using postman? if yes then use fiddler to see differences between postman request and app request